# Android camera pre-start preview for faster camera use

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using QRCodeReaderView https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView for implementing my own QR Code Scanner and it works well but the camera still starts slow (3-4 seconds) and I came up with the idea to pre start previewing the camera before using (keeping the camera open when the focus is on the fragment that has the button to start scanning so it could be opened right away when needed) and I tried everything but it seems like I don't understand the concept and it still starts slow.
Here is the code for the QRCodeReaderView:

```
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.ChecksumException;
import com.google.zxing.FormatException;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.ResultPoint;
import com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.CameraManager;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class QRCodeReaderView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    public interface OnQRCodeReadListener {

        public void onQRCodeRead(String text, PointF[] points);

        public void cameraNotFound();

        public void QRCodeNotFoundOnCamImage();
    }

    private OnQRCodeReadListener mOnQRCodeReadListener;

    private static final String TAG = QRCodeReaderView.class.getName();

    private QRCodeReader mQRCodeReader;
    private int mPreviewWidth;
    private int mPreviewHeight;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private CameraManager mCameraManager;

    public QRCodeReaderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public QRCodeReaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public void setOnQRCodeReadListener(OnQRCodeReadListener onQRCodeReadListener) {
        mOnQRCodeReadListener = onQRCodeReadListener;
    }

    public CameraManager getCameraManager() {
        return mCameraManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void init() {
        if (checkCameraHardware(getContext())) {
            mCameraManager = new CameraManager(getContext());
            mHolder = this.getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  // Need to set this flag despite it's deprecated
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: Camera not found");
            if (mOnQRCodeReadListener != null) {
                mOnQRCodeReadListener.cameraNotFound();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * *************************************************
     * SurfaceHolder.Callback,Camera.PreviewCallback
     * **************************************************
     */

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // Indicate camera, our View dimensions
            mCameraManager.openDriver(holder, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Can not openDriver: " + e.getMessage());
            mCameraManager.closeDriver();
        }

        try {
            mQRCodeReader = new QRCodeReader();
            mCameraManager.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            mCameraManager.closeDriver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        mCameraManager.getCamera().setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCameraManager.getCamera().stopPreview();
        mCameraManager.getCamera().release();
        mCameraManager.closeDriver();
    }

    // Called when camera take a frame
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = mCameraManager.buildLuminanceSource(data, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);

        HybridBinarizer hybBin = new HybridBinarizer(source);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(hybBin);

        try {
            Result result = mQRCodeReader.decode(bitmap);

            // Notify we found a QRCode
            if (mOnQRCodeReadListener != null) {
                // Transform resultPoints to View coordinates
                PointF[] transformedPoints = transformToViewCoordinates(result.getResultPoints());
                mOnQRCodeReadListener.onQRCodeRead(result.getText(), transformedPoints);
            }

        } catch (ChecksumException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ChecksumException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // Notify QR not found
            if (mOnQRCodeReadListener != null) {
                mOnQRCodeReadListener.QRCodeNotFoundOnCamImage();
            }
        } catch (FormatException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FormatException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mQRCodeReader.reset();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: preview surface does not exist");
            return;
        }

        //preview_width = width;
        //preview_height = height;

        mPreviewWidth = mCameraManager.getPreviewSize().x;
        mPreviewHeight = mCameraManager.getPreviewSize().y;


        mCameraManager.stopPreview();
        mCameraManager.getCamera().setPreviewCallback(this);
        mCameraManager.getCamera().setDisplayOrientation(90); // Portrait mode

        mCameraManager.startPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Transform result to surfaceView coordinates
     * <p/>
     * This method is needed because coordinates are given in landscape camera coordinates.
     * Now is working but transform operations aren't very explained
     * <p/>
     * TODO re-write this method explaining each single value
     *
     * @return a new PointF array with transformed points
     */
    private PointF[] transformToViewCoordinates(ResultPoint[] resultPoints) {

        PointF[] transformedPoints = new PointF[resultPoints.length];
        int index = 0;
        if (resultPoints != null) {
            float previewX = mCameraManager.getPreviewSize().x;
            float previewY = mCameraManager.getPreviewSize().y;
            float scaleX = this.getWidth() / previewY;
            float scaleY = this.getHeight() / previewX;

            for (ResultPoint point : resultPoints) {
                PointF tmppoint = new PointF((previewY - point.getY()) * scaleX, point.getX() * scaleY);
                transformedPoints[index] = tmppoint;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return transformedPoints;

    }


    /**
     * Check if this device has a camera
     */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
            // this device has a front camera
            return true;
        } else if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
            // this device has any camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my fragment that uses it:

```
package com.breadwallet.presenter.fragments;

import com.breadwallet.R;
import com.breadwallet.presenter.activities.ScanResultActivity;
import com.breadwallet.tools.animation.SpringAnimator;
import com.breadwallet.tools.qrcode.QRCodeReaderView;

public class MainFragmentDecoder extends Fragment implements QRCodeReaderView.OnQRCodeReadListener {

    public static final String TAG = "MainFragmentDecoder";

    private boolean accessGranted = true;
    private TextView myTextView;
    private static QRCodeReaderView mydecoderview;
    private ImageView camera_guide_image;
    private Intent intent;
    public static MainFragmentDecoder mainFragmentDecoder;
    private RelativeLayout layout;

    public MainFragmentDecoder() {
        mainFragmentDecoder = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_decoder, container, false);

        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScanResultActivity.class);
        myTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);
        camera_guide_image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_guide_image);
        SpringAnimator.showExpandCameraGuide(camera_guide_image);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_decoder_layout);
        mydecoderview = new QRCodeReaderView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mydecoderview.setOnQRCodeReadListener(mainFragmentDecoder);
        if (mydecoderview != null)
            mydecoderview.getCameraManager().startPreview();

    }

    /**
     * Called when a QR is decoded
     * "text" : the text encoded in QR
     * "points" : points where QR control points are placed
     */

    @Override
    public void onQRCodeRead(String text, PointF[] points) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (accessGranted) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        accessGranted = true;
                    }
                }, 300);
                accessGranted = false;
//            Log.e(TAG, "Activity STARTED!!!!!");
                intent.putExtra("result", text);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    // Called when your device have no camera
    @Override
    public void cameraNotFound() {
        Log.d(TAG, "No Camera found!");
    }

    // Called when there's no QR codes in the camera preview image
    @Override
    public void QRCodeNotFoundOnCamImage() {
//        Log.d(TAG, "No QR Code found!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new CameraOpenerTask().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "In onPause");
        mydecoderview.getCameraManager().stopPreview();
        layout.removeView(mydecoderview);

    }

    private class CameraOpenerTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    layout.addView(mydecoderview, 0);
                }
            }, 1300);

            Log.e(TAG, "The camera started");
        }
    }

    public void stopCamera() {
        if (mydecoderview != null) {
            mydecoderview.getCameraManager().stopPreview();
        }
        mydecoderview = null;

    }

}
```

I tried:

1. camera.StartPreview() earlier than using it.
2. pre-create the mydecoderview and then simply make it visible when
   pressing the button but it still takes 3-4 seconds to start it.

Comment: Here's someone suffering from a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359063/the-startpreview-function-is-slow-any-work-around Have you tried any of these workarounds?

Comment: Thanks, I did not see that when searching for this solution, will check it tomorrow and see if works!

Comment: So the suggested post did not contain any helpful information but thanks for the try

Answer (score -1):

You could try *photo app* in **CyanogenMod** (11 version) firmware, maybe this is just that you're searching for?
Download from somewhere it source and add its to your code.

Comment: I need to make it independent (not to use any dependencies) so I need someone to tell me how to pre-start the camera

Comment: What if Cyanogenmod/LineageOS cam app doesn't have major dependencies?